# Can i use vscode instead of cloud9 for web developement

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ide, cloud9-ide

I'm currently going through the web developer bootcamp and got to the cloud9 setup segment, and apparently amazon bought the site. This is a problem for 2 reasons: after a year they charge for the service and that i can't register my phone because of an error on the site. I'm currently using vscode for most of my needs and i wanted to know if i can get by with it for the rest of the tutorial, which includes nodeJs, mongoDB, express etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best IDE is always the one that best suites your needs. If there’s features Cloud9 has that you can’t live without (live collaboration?) then it’s going to be better than Visual Studio Code. It’s all a personal preference.

My personal preference would be Visual Studio Code because:

```
It’s open source, cross platform and actively worked on.
It’s free
It’s fast enough.
It’s highly customizable (themes, key mappings, extensions).
I don’t need my IDE to live in the cloud, I have git and configuration sync so my IDE is the same on any of my machines.
Vast number of extensions for anything you can imagine (SCM integration, languages, linters, debuggers, IoT, cloud computing, etc etc)
It’s supported by a very large company and isn’t going anyway.
```

Take a look at comparison between Cloud9 IDE vs. Visual Studio Code in the following link
https://stackshare.io/stackups/visual-studio-code-vs-cloud9-ide